# Error "Attempt to de-reference a null object " when receiving a list

Tags: apex, visualforce

I would like to ask for help with a code that I am doing, it is actually quite simple.Well what i'm doing is getting the data of a custom object in one method, and in another method i'm trying to insert into a string list just the name field of the first object, but for some reason i keep getting the error of "Attempting to dereference a null object
"
This is my code:

```java
public List<String>headContasName;
public List<Oportunidade_de_Negocios__c> oppNegociosAll;

public List<Oportunidade_de_Negocios__c>getOppNegociosAll(){
    if(oppNegociosAll == null){
        oppNegociosAll = [Select Id, Variedade__c, Variedade__r.Name, Oferta_Venda__c, LastModifiedDate, Licenciado__c, Safra__c, Demanda_Compra__c,
                            Conta__c, Conta__r.Name  
                            FROM Oportunidade_de_Negocios__c
                            WHERE Safra__c =: safraActual
                            ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC ];
    }
    System.debug('oppNegociosAll' + oppNegociosAll);
    return oppNegociosAll;
}

// this is the method that should  be getting the list of //string
public List<String>getHeadContasName(){
    try{
        if(headContasName == null){
            for(Oportunidade_de_Negocios__c i:getOppNegociosAll()){
                headContasName.add(i.Conta__r.Name);
            }
        }
        System.debug('headContasName'+headContasName);
        return headContasName;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        return null;            
    }
}
```

Vfp

```html
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <apex:repeat value="{!HeadContasName}" var="heading" rendered="true">
                <td>
                    {!heading}
                </td>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I appreciate who can help, I'm in this problem for hours.

Comment: Is getOppNegociosAll returning any records? headContasName could be null at your debug statement. Does the error message include a line number, if so please add the full error message and highlight which line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the list first:

```
if(headContasName==null){
  headContasName = new List<String>();
  for(Oportunidade_de_Negocios__c i:getOppNegociosAll()){
     headContasName.add(i.Conta__r.Name);
  }
}
```

Also, the try-catch block is unnecessary here, as there's no way to throw a catchable exception if you've written your code correctly.